# Android database testing - using Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder() passes exact same test that Room.databaseBuilder() does not

Tags: android, database, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am writing units tests for an app's Room database. Here is relevant code when using `Room.databaseBuilder()`

```
@Before
public void createDb() {
    Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
    db = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "AppDatabase").build();
    itemDao = db.itemDao();
}
```

The test fails here and the error is `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: item.id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY[1555])`. (I think I know what causes the error, I need I don't have an auto generated primary key for entries so a record is inserted with an id already in the table. Anyway, that's not what my question is.)

And same method, using `Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder()`. Here the test passes.

```
@Before
void createDb() {
    Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
    db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class).build();
    itemDao = db.itemDao();
}
```

And the test itself is:

```
@Test
public void writeItemAndReadInList() {
    float value = 3.0f;
    Item item = new Item(value, new Date());
    itemDao.insert(item);
    List<Item> all = itemDao.getAll();
    assertEquals(all.get(0).getValue(), value);
}
```

So the question is why does the first method fail and the second one pass? What difference is that one database is created in memory and the other not? If the problem is with inserting with unique primary keys, shouldn't it be present in both methods? Unless that is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Room.databaseBuilder(..).build()` won't drop your database between runs, it is persistent. `Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(...).build()` it is not (all data is lost when the process is killed), that's why you're not getting unique constraint exceptions when you first run the test.

Comment: Yes that's right! I've modified the test method to insert two items instead of one, and I am happy to say they now both fail successfully.